# history_meta Versioned mapper throws an exception with bi-directional relationships

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, versioning, recipe

I'm using the history_meta recipe found [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/_modules/examples/versioned_history/history_meta.html) to version my declarative objects. However, when I have a bi-directional relationship between two models, the mapper fails to find/initialize the other model's mapper. So something like this.

```py
class Child(Versioned, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("parent.id"))
    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")


class Parent(Versioned, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent")
```

will give the error

```py
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper Mapper|Child|child, expression 'Parent' failed to locate a name ("name 'Parent' is not defined"). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class '__main__.Child'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.
```

Moving the relationships below the class definitions fixes the issue, but this is an undesirable solution. It looks like the mapper called by history meta needs all the related classes to be created before being called.

Is there any way to make history_meta work with bi-directional relationships in this way?

Answer (score 0):

A good workaround for this issue is to use `backref` instead of `back_populates`. So the example becomes:

```py
class Child(Versioned, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("parent.id"))


class Parent(Versioned, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child", backref="parent")
```